# Colvis don't work for datatable with yadcf

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

I don't understand why colvis don't work for my table.
I include these css and js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColVis/css/dataTables.colVis.css">
<script src="https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColVis/js/dataTables.colVis.js"></script>
```

and then for initialisation

```
dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip'
```

so my code is like this:

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable({


        dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bStateSave": true

    }).yadcf([{
```

But this solution don't work for my table because Colvis doesn't appear and then destroy other css/layout of table.
Here my table: [MY TABLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/18/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the datatables docs and understand the difference between 1.9 Hungarian notation syntax and the camelCase of 1.10

replace `dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',` with `"sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',`

And include the colVis css/js in your jsfiddle

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/25/)

Comment: thanks, you are a killer!  but I see that Colvis change some css Table elements. Is possible to fix?

Comment: possible? bet that yes, after all its all in the css, but its up to you to do the midifications in your css.